# Why are localdb tables missing in SSMS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Using VS2015 I can successfully connect to a localdb-based sql database.

However, when I expand the database in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) see 0 tables, yet in VS2015 my tables are visible.

here are some pictures:

[missing tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Mcr.png)

[tables present in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uspV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first shutdown any programs which have the database file opened. Such as Visual Studio, or IIS/IISExpress (or your console app.) Before you can edit the database using SSMS.

You should also ensure you have opened the correct database in SSMS, and not created a new/duplicate database.

You should also use the same server name in SSMS as is used in the connection string in Visual Studio and also your app. This will rule out accidentally creating/referencing a duplicate database.

It may help to open `services.msc` and stop the SQL Server service (not localdb), then re-check your SSMS, VS and console app and verify you're not accidentally connecting to SQL Server from one of them. It's possible to have separate databases with the same name in different MSSQL instances.

Comment: disconnected it in VS, still does not show up in ssms, or maybe I didn't disconnect it properly, how would you disconnect it?